# Apply Rails core fix locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I hit a bug in Rails 4.1.4 that is recently fixed in Rails core by: [Fix potenital infinite recursion in changed_for_autosave? #16640](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16640)

How can I temporarily patch in this fix locally until I've upgraded to a Rails version that has this? The fix is a change to activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb

I already have an extension for AR::Base that I call from an initializer that includes itself via `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)`

I tried adding a module inline in that file for AutosaveAssociation with the changed method.

**Update**

config/intializers/01_extensions.rb

```
require "active_record_extension"
```

active_record_extension.rb

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
  ...
  end

  module AutosaveAssociation
    def nested_records_changed_for_autosave?
      return false if @_nested_records_changed_for_autosave_already_called ||= false
      @_nested_records_changed_for_autosave_already_called = true
      begin
        self.class._reflections.values.any? do |reflection|
          if reflection.options[:autosave]
            association = association_instance_get(reflection.name)
            association && Array.wrap(association.target).any? { |a| a.changed_for_autosave? }
          end
        end
      ensure
        @_nested_records_changed_for_autosave_already_called = false
      end
    end
  end # module Autosave

end
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

Comment: What does your initializer/extension look like?

Comment: Added to question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
module ActiveRecord#Extension
  module AutosaveAssociation
    def nested_records_changed_for_autosave?
      puts "new"
    end
  end
end

#ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)

class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation

  def initialize
    nested_records_changed_for_autosave?
  end
end
A.new
=> new
```

Comment: So I call A.new at the end of that file? Wouldn't that just run the method nested_records_changed_for_autosave? out of context when the app starts up?

Comment: Ahh @rigyt I totally missed your comment, sorry about that! No it won't run the method it will just "replace" it. And the replaced method will be called instead.